# How do I only load more items when the user scroll all the way down?

Tags: meteor

In my project, all the items are loaded at once, and this will affect the performance if there were many items to be loaded.

Am trying to load 9 items each time the user scroll all the way to the end of the page.

any guidance on how to implement it please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best pattern for pagination for Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739054/best-pattern-for-pagination-for-meteor)

Comment: This is called "infinite scrolling" and has been asked and answered several times before. [This is an excellent tutorial](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling)

Comment: There is even package for this https://atmospherejs.com/staringatlights/infinite-scroll